# How to check if two 'lines' overlap?

Tags: javascript, overlap

I know, its a dumb question, but I need to check if two periods of time (in `epoch`) *overlap* with each other. I just don't know if those checks will be sufficient.

```
TLPeriod.prototype.isOverlapping = function(period) {
    if( period.toPoints().start.getEpoch() < this.toPoints().start.getEpoch()
        &&
        this.toPoints().start.getEpoch() < period.toPoints().end.getEpoch())
        return true;
    if(this.toPoints().end.getEpoch() > period.toPoints().start.getEpoch())
        return true;
    return false;
};
```

I know, i should write [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but it would take lots of time to get an answer.

It could be quickly summarized to:

Two lines on *the same axis* with points:

**|(this.start),(this.end)|**

&

**|(period.start),(period.end)|**

How to check if they overlap?

```
OVERLAP!
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|
this.start  period.start     this.end     period.end

NO OVERLAP!
|-----------|              |-------------|
this.start  this.end     period.start  period.end

OVERLAP!
|-----------------|--------|-------------|
period.start  this.start  this.end     period.end
```

Comment: sort the periods by start such that `(a, b) < (c, d)`, then they overlap iff `c < d`, and is included iff `d < b`, and don't overlap if `b < c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An opposite question: when do they *not* overlap? The answer: when the first one starts after the second one ends, or when the second one starts after the first one ends.  So

```
TLPeriod.prototype.isOverlapping = function(period) {
   return !(
      period.toPoints().start.getEpoch() > this.toPoints().end.getEpoch() ||
      this.toPoints().start.getEpoch() > period.toPoints().end.getEpoch()
   );
}
```